# Completar Argumento de Range em Swift 3.0

Tags: string, ios, swift, iphone, apple

Eu estava utilizando normalmente este código em um projeto Swift 2.0, depois resolví atualizar o projeto pra versão 3.0 e adaptar algumas funções que mudaram... Só que o ultimo argumento "range" eu não consigo adaptar.

Código em Swift 2.0:

```
if let range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(invalidCharacters, options: nil, range:Range<String.Index>(start: string.startIndex, end: string.endIndex)) {

           return false
 }
```

Código em Swift 3.0:

```
if let range = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invalidCharacters, options: [], range: ){

        return false

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa passar o último argumento se você quiser verificar toda a string:

```
return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invalidCharacters) != nil
```

Se voce quiser passar a range você precisa fazer da seguinte maneira:

`string.startIndex..<string.endIndex`

No seu caso:

```
if let range = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invalidCharacters, options: [], range: string.startIndex..<string.endIndex){
    print(range)
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Leo, deu certinho!

Comment: De nada Jadson.